# How to count files that contain at least two lines using find or xargs?

Tags: find, xargs

I have several `.tsv` files in a directory, and I wanted to count them. The files in the directory `dir` are named `file1.tsv`, `file2.tsv`, `file3tsv`, ...`fileN.tsv`. This is what I have done so far and it works fine:

```
find dir/file* -maxdepth 1 -type f | wc -l
```

But I want to apply one other condition; I want to count only files that contain at least 2 lines. How can I use `find` or `xargs` command to perform this operation effectively, considering there may be hundreds of thousands of files in `dir` in the future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That one is not efficient, because if you had that many files, invoking `find` with that glob would cause an *Argument list too long* error. What you should do instead is this:

```sh
find dir -name '*.tsv' -exec awk 'FNR == 2 { printf "."; nextfile }' {} + | wc -c
```

Place additional filters such as **-maxdepth**, **-type**, etc. before **-exec**. The **nextfile** statement is considered a GNU extension, but all mainstream AWKs have it now.